# JQuery-File-Upload button with jquery mobile style

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I used jquery-file-upload plugin with jquery-1.8.3 and jquery-mobile-1.2. It worked fine.

But today, I updated to jquery-1.9 and jquery-mobile-1.3, and the button style has changed.

I have added them to jsfiddle.
I want it to look like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gcoordinate/MRALZ/1/)

```
<span class="fileinput-button" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">
<span>添加文件</span>
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple />
</span>
```

But it looks like [that](http://jsfiddle.net/gcoordinate/X23dx/)

```
<span class="fileinput-button" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">
<span>添加文件</span>
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple />
</span>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the new version, jQuery Mobile changed the way it deals with file inputs. From the [announcement post](http://blog.jquerymobile.com/2013/02/20/jquery-mobile-1-3-0-released/):

> Now that file input types are becoming more supported by mobile platforms, we’ve added automatic styling for these as part of jQuery Mobile.

And indeed, it generates HTML code around the input:

```
<div class="ui-input-text ui-shadow-inset ui-corner-all ui-btn-shadow ui-body-c">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c">
</div>
```

A solution would be to prevent jQuery Mobile to style your element, simply by adding the attribute `data-role="none"`

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple data-role="none"/>
```

See the jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/X23dx/1/

**Update for jQuery Mobile 1.4**

To obtain a (kind of) similar result with the 1.4 version, you need to add some new classes to the surrounding `<span>`:

```
<span class="ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left ui-corner-all fileinput-button">
    <span>添加文件</span>
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple data-role="none"/>
</span>
```

See the updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X23dx/173/

Comment: Please advise how to get this working for jquery 1.4 ?

Comment: I meant jquery mobile 1.4

Comment: @kurrodu Please see my update. Right now it is a bit of a guess, because the upgrade guide is not available yet, but you should get an approaching result.

Comment: Your suggestion really helps, many thanks for your prompt response. Would have been good if I found your answer before spending a day over the issue. How could I increase the width of the button (without adding more text) ?

Comment: @kurrodu Simply add `width: 200px` to the `.fileinput-button` CSS selector: http://jsfiddle.net/X23dx/174/

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work correctly of Firefox. Last character of text is replaced by ... (text-overflow: ellipsis; I guess), and I haven't found way to fix it. This is caused by `transform: translate(-300px, 0) scale(4);` I've tried to replace it with size and margin properties to achieve same effect, but no luck.

Comment: To fix ellipses in Firefox - remove text-overflow: ellipses; for ui-btn-inner